# Eclipse 4.2.1 Error installing Google plug in 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

i am new to the eclipse and i am trying to install the google plug in for eclipse and i get the following :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.0.v201302131858-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.0.v201302131858-rel-r42)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.0.v201302131858-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.0.v201302131858-rel-r42) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.css.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Eclipse Java EE, not Eclipse SDK..

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2

Comment: thank u for the help 
the Eclipse Java EE Workd!

im sorry for the newbbie question.

and thanks a lot for the quick response .

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin Fritz said, use preferably the Eclipse Java EE package. If you don't want to install Eclipse from scratch, you can also install the needed plugins from the [Juno update site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/) or the [WTP update site](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno). Install the WTP packages. Just ask if you don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this page http://www.shekhargovindarajan.com/tips-n-tricks/solved-requires-bundle-org-eclipse-wst-xml-core-error-while-installing-google-plugin-in-fedora-eclipse/

> Launch Eclipse. Click on Help>Install New Software. On the subsequent window titled “Available Software”, click on blue link ‘Available Software Sites’. Look for the URL http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo in the list of Software Sites. Select and click on Enable (button on the right). Click on OK.
>
> Back on the “Available Software” window, type the URL http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5 in the field labeled “Work with:” . Click on Add. This will show Plugin and SDKs in the bottom pane. Check the boxes against them and click on Next. Follow the onscreen instructions. This will install the Google plugin and SDK. When prompted, restart Eclipse.

You may obviously need to update the links to be `4.2` instead of `3.5` and `juno` instead of `galileo`.